# How to Select jCalender date when I click Mouse on some Day

Tags: java, swing, date, jcalendar

I use mouse click event. When I click to select specific date on it but nothing happened inside mouse click event. I use this code. I don't want to need use `JDateChooser`

```
jCalendar.getDayChooser().addPropertyChangeListener("day", new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override

        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()+ ": " + e.getNewValue());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by "e.i doesnt want to need use jDatechooser".
To get the date you could use :

```
jCalendar.getDayChooser().addPropertyChangeListener(
        //property sliderListener detects change of date in date chooser
        (PropertyChangeEvent evt)-> { dateChooserPropertChanged(evt);   });

private void dateChooserPropertChanged(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

    if ("calendar".equals(evt.getPropertyName())
                || "date".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {

        System.out.println("date is :"+ jCalendar.getDayChooser().getDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: i mean i want to get selected  date using jCalender not jDatechooser

Comment: I'm newbie thanks for your help c0der.if i use this code in my mouseclicked event is that correct

Answer (score 3):

```
    cal = new JCalendar();
    cal.setWeekOfYearVisible(false);
    cal.getDayChooser().addPropertyChangeListener("day", new PropertyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()
                + ": " + e.getNewValue());

    }
});
```

Still, that will only give you the day that the user picked, not the entire date.

Instead of using `e.getnewvalue();` , use `cal.getDate.toString()` so you can show the entire date.

Comment: k i will check and do it

Comment: can i use this code inside my mouse clicked event and can you tell me what is the that "day" means

Comment: i use your code .it works fine but there is a problem i want to select some date when i clicked on that date in jCalendar .but when i use this jCalendarMouseClicked() nothing happen .but jButtonActionPerformed() code work properly .where is the problem help me

Comment: this seems helpful to your query:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179100/jdatechooser-mouseclicked-event-doesnt-get-fired